# iPhone list style like UL LI

Tags: iphone, objective-c, list, html-lists

Is there a way to create a list style like the UL LI for HTML on the iPhone in a textView? Why i want this is because when i have a long text there will be minimal 2 rules text show.

Example:

1. Hello i'm a monkey 
   from the zoo!
2. Hello i'm a monkey 
   from the zoo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way that worked for me is to use a UIWebView and add the text as HTML.
this is apple recommendation for rich text.

```
    UIWebView *webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 130,300 ,230)];

webview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
webview.opaque=NO;
webview.delegate=self;

    NSString *text = @"<ul><li>item 1</li><li>item 2</li></ul>";
NSString *cssPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"style" ofType:@"css"];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

NSString *html =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\"en\"><head><link rel=\"stylesheet\"  href=\"%@\" type=\"text/css\" /></head><body>%@</body></html>",cssPath,text];

[webview loadHTMLString:html baseURL:baseURL];  
[self addSubview:webview];
```

And don't forget to create the "style.css" file in your project.

good luck
shani

Answer (score 2):

Use `UIWebView`, you can pass it arbitrary HTML as a `NSString`.